# View is picking the default global value instead of the changed value of that global variable

Tags: angular

I have declared a global variable ,its value is changing inside for loop ,
but when i am accesing that variable in .html view it is picking up the glolbal variable instead of changed value of that vairable

Event_count:any=[];

getStoreInformationValues(){

```
this._dataService.getStoreInfo().subscribe(
  (result1 )=> 
  { 
   this.Store_data=result1;
   for( let i=0;i<this.Store_data.length;i++){
    this.Jsonobj3=this.Store_data[i];
    this.Event_count[0]=this.Jsonobj3['store_no']


  }


   console.log("store data" ,this.Store_data);
   console.log("event count value" +this.Event_count);


},
(error)=>{

})
```

//CODE FOR VIEW

```
{{Event_count}} //it is picking the global value
```

Comment: and what is logged here: console.log("event count value" +this.Event_count); ?

Comment: @Nitsan it is picking the value which i coming from api that is 8299,